# Remove part of the url query element that is generated when clicking on other tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am using jquery tabify, http://unwrongest.com/projects/tabify/, to create a tab like feature for my menu.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/janjarfalk/6Y6Pa/1/

I am creating a menu like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li class="active"><a href="#contentHome">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#contentGuestbook">Guestbook</a></li>
<li><a href="#contentLinks">Links</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="content" id="contentHome">Content for Home</div>
<div class="content" id="contentGuestbook">My guestbook</div>
<div class="content" id="contentLinks">Links</div>
```

The tabs will be added automatically as anchor link to my url, reading whatever that i have on my url. I need to have a url (for links tab only) such as ***{domain name}/{controller}/{method}/{articleId}#contentLinks-tab***, examples:

- http://www.test.com/site/shipping/5/#contentLinks-tab
- http://www.test.com/site/delivery/3/#contentLinks-tab

while the rest will only be http://www.test.com/site#home-tab, etc. As you could see from the demo, the "{id}-tab" is auto generated based on the id. However, the problem arises if i am already on http://www.test.com/links/shipping/5/#contentLinks-tab of the links page, and if I were to go to other tabs like guestbook or home, the /shipping/5/#contentHome-tab will follow.

Can please advise how can I remove the /shipping/5/ even when I am on links tab, and hovering the rest of the tab? Sorry I was not able to provide much coding as I have no idea about doing it. Hence, really appreciate someone can shine some lights. Many thanks.

Comment: Is it always going to be `/shipping/5` that you want to replace? or will it be `/random/number`, so we need to match a certain case i the string?

Comment: it is not always going to be /shipping/5, it may be /delivery/12 etc. yup you are right about the /random/number

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one to answer, as jsFiddle is obviously missing the `/shipping/5` part of the URL; And if understand correctly we're basically trying to change the functionality of the plugin.

At any rate, it's a little hacky, but you could try changing the `href` attribute of the Home and Guestbook links using javascript. So first give the Home and Guestbook links IDs:

```
<a href="#contentHome" id="home">Home</a>
<a href="#contentGuestbook" id="guestbook">Guestbook</a>
```

Then use jQuery to replace the URLs after Tabify has initialized:

```
$('#menu').tabify();
$('#home').attr('href','/site#contentHome-tab');
$('#guestbook').attr('href','/site#contentGuestbook-tab');
```

Which would equate to `http://www.test.com/site#contentHome-tab`, etc., effectively getting rid of the undesired part of the URL.

Or if that doesn't work (hard to tell when using such a plugin on jsFiddle), you could get even more hacky and instead add onclick listeners to the Home and Guestbook tabs:

```
$('#home').click(function() {
  window.location.href = "/site#contentHome-tab";
});​
```

I normally would never do something like this, but when you're working with plugins sometimes you gotta get a little hacky to achieve the desired effect =P

Hope this helps.